# Text bleeding through into next div?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web design and was running into an issue here so I recreated an ugly version to show you what was happening.  I'm wondering why the text is not increasing the size of the div and instead running into the other one.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 font-family: chunk;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 2em;
}
body,td,th {
 font-family: abel;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
#about {
 background-color: #D79394;
 font-family: abel;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
#aboutCopy {
 width: 47.1%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-size: 1.3vw;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#about img {
 width: 47%;
 margin-left: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#about #aboutCopy h1 {
 margin-bottom: -5px;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: chunk;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#dummu {
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #61D2F4;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section id="about">
  <div id="aboutCopy">
   <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
   <p>It All Began in a Poker Game.</p>
  <p> In the mid-1960’s, Michael Schroeder was in Austin, Texas, engaged in his favorite pastime. Another player, short on cash but long on nerve, covered Schroeder’s bet by offering “half my restaurant.” Schroeder’s three 3’s beat a pair of queens. It was time to pay up, the owner of the barbecue restaurant insisted that he meant “half the space,” not a “half interest.”&nbsp;Schroeder’s “half” was an empty room in the back.</p>
   <p>Angered by the sleazy tactic, Schroeder collected his grandmother’s barbecue recipes and set up a restaurant-within-a-restaurant.</p>
   <p>Customers knew of the shared-space arrangement. And, although his seating space was limited to 40 people, his barbecue was so superior that customers were soon asking specifically to be seated in the back forty. Business in the front section dwindled; Schroeder bought out the owner and turned it into a legendary barbecue chain. </p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>sfsfsafasf</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>fsfsa</p>
   <p>fas</p>
   <p>afs </p>
  </div>

   
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hGtdKEW.jpg" alt=""/>
</section>
<section id="dummu"></section>

</body>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome. Can you post a screenshot and mention what browser you have an issue on?

Comment: @mplungjan: It works fine in full screen for me but not in the snippet. Must be the width setting in percentage which is causing the difference.

Comment: hmm it seems to do it on full screen, my phone, and the snippet for me.  here is screen http://i.imgur.com/NODCiEX.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this `#about { overflow: hidden;}` it is because of `float` for the children(#aboutCopy)

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 font-family: chunk;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 2em;
}
body,td,th {
 font-family: abel;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
#about {
 background-color: #D79394;
 font-family: abel;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#aboutCopy {
 width: 47.1%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-size: 1.3vw;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#about img {
 width: 47%;
 margin-left: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#about #aboutCopy h1 {
 margin-bottom: -5px;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: chunk;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#dummu {
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #61D2F4;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section id="about">
  <div id="aboutCopy">
   <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
   <p>It All Began in a Poker Game.</p>
  <p> In the mid-1960’s, Michael Schroeder was in Austin, Texas, engaged in his favorite pastime. Another player, short on cash but long on nerve, covered Schroeder’s bet by offering “half my restaurant.” Schroeder’s three 3’s beat a pair of queens. It was time to pay up, the owner of the barbecue restaurant insisted that he meant “half the space,” not a “half interest.”&nbsp;Schroeder’s “half” was an empty room in the back.</p>
   <p>Angered by the sleazy tactic, Schroeder collected his grandmother’s barbecue recipes and set up a restaurant-within-a-restaurant.</p>
   <p>Customers knew of the shared-space arrangement. And, although his seating space was limited to 40 people, his barbecue was so superior that customers were soon asking specifically to be seated in the back forty. Business in the front section dwindled; Schroeder bought out the owner and turned it into a legendary barbecue chain. </p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>sfsfsafasf</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>fsfsa</p>
   <p>fas</p>
   <p>afs </p>
  </div>

   
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hGtdKEW.jpg" alt=""/>
</section>
<section id="dummu"></section>

</body>
```

Comment: That did it I believe!  Thank you!

Comment: Uh oh that kind of broke something else in my actual site.  Now the div gets funky.  Should be like this http://i.imgur.com/GaVLo1l.jpg but is doing this now http://i.imgur.com/e06xiI5.jpg - any workaround for this?

Comment: or try adding `display:inline-block; width:100%;` instead of `overflow:hidden` @user4340635

Comment: There ya go! That did it! THanks again answer given

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example with `overflow: hidden` in `#about`

You can also read more about clearfix to understand this topic - http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 font-family: chunk;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 2em;
}
body,td,th {
 font-family: abel;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
#about {
 background-color: #D79394;
 font-family: abel;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#aboutCopy {
 width: 47.1%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-size: 1.3vw;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#about img {
 width: 47%;
 margin-left: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#about #aboutCopy h1 {
 margin-bottom: -5px;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: chunk;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#dummu {
 background-color: #61D2F4;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section id="about">
  <div id="aboutCopy">
   <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
   <p>It All Began in a Poker Game.</p>
  <p> In the mid-1960’s, Michael Schroeder was in Austin, Texas, engaged in his favorite pastime. Another player, short on cash but long on nerve, covered Schroeder’s bet by offering “half my restaurant.” Schroeder’s three 3’s beat a pair of queens. It was time to pay up, the owner of the barbecue restaurant insisted that he meant “half the space,” not a “half interest.”&nbsp;Schroeder’s “half” was an empty room in the back.</p>
   <p>Angered by the sleazy tactic, Schroeder collected his grandmother’s barbecue recipes and set up a restaurant-within-a-restaurant.</p>
   <p>Customers knew of the shared-space arrangement. And, although his seating space was limited to 40 people, his barbecue was so superior that customers were soon asking specifically to be seated in the back forty. Business in the front section dwindled; Schroeder bought out the owner and turned it into a legendary barbecue chain. </p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>sfsfsafasf</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>fsfsa</p>
   <p>fas</p>
   <p>afs </p>
  </div>

   
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hGtdKEW.jpg" alt=""/>
</section>
<section id="dummu"></section>

</body>
```